# Go/Cgo: produce static library without definitions of Go runtime functions

Tags: c, go, linker, static-libraries, cgo

Is there a way to produce a C static library from Go code, but **without Go runtime function definitions**?

**Rationale**:

- `Project A` creates a C static library with `go build -buildmode=c-archive`, `libA.a` .
- Works well: `project B` uses pure C and is able to easily create an executable, statically linking with `libA.a`, all is fine.
- Problem 1: `project C` happens to also use Go, but would like to use `libA.a` **as a regular C library**. Now it has a link problem: the Go runtime functions such as e.g. `_cgo_panic` are now defined both in `project C` runtime (as it uses Go) and in `libA.a`.
- Problem 2: `project D` uses pure C, same as B. Yet it wants to use two different libraries from `project A`, e.g. `libA.a` and some `libA2.a`. Sadly, it does not link either, because Go runtime functions are now defined in both `libA.a` and `libA2.a`.

The problems faced by `project C` and `project D` could be easily resolved if `project A` could produce its libraries without the Go runtime definitions inside. `Project C` could just link with `libA.a`. `Project D` would link with `libA.a`, `libA2.a` and some `libGo.a` that would contain definitions of all the Go runtime stuff.

What I tried:

- Using linker flags at 'project C' level, such as `-Wl,--allow-multiple-definition`. Now its build fails with a cryptic message '*function symbol table not sorted by program counter*'.
- Manually removing `go.o` from 'libA.a' (as it's just an "ar" archive): didn't work as 'go.o' also contained implementations of my exported functions, so I've removed too much.
- Using `go build -buildmode=c-shared`. As expected, it produces a dynamic library which uses another format, so I could not directly use it as a static library.

**Any solution at the client side (such as finding a proper way to ignore duplicate definitions at the link stage for `project C`) would be also considered a valid answer.** 
I can also accept a negative answer (no solution) if it provides enough evidence.

**Update:** see a related question [Is there a way to include multiple c-archive packages in a single binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34333107/is-there-a-way-to-include-multiple-c-archive-packages-in-a-single-binary)

Comment: Go code requires the go runtime, and loading multiple instances of the go runtime is not supported. You cannot use go in this way.

Comment: Thanks, this is probably the answer. Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: As far as I know it's only documented by omission, I would not expect it to work unless it was specifically allowed. It would not be a trivial task to get multiple go runtime instances to cooperate within the same process space.

Answer (score 0):

With the current implementation it's not going to work to use `-buildmode=c-archive` multiple times and put the results into multiple shared libraries, as you've discovered. The essential problem is that there has to be only one Go runtime, but you have multiple runtimes. When using `-buildmode=c-archive` there's no way to isolate the different runtimes.

The `-buildmode=c-shared` libraries differ from `buildmode=c-archive` in that they are built with `-Bsymbolic` which forces all their local references to be local. The effect is that we have multiple Go runtimes, but they don't refer to each other so there is no confusion.

You *could* try adding `-Wl,-Bsymbolic` to build each shared library that includes Go code in `c-archive` if your C code doesn't mind being linked with `-Bsymbolic`.

I wish you luck.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've tried the following: go build -buildmode=c-archive -ldflags="-extldflags '-Wl,-Bsymbolic'" to build my library. It looks like there was no effect. Do you see any other way of propagating the linker flags?

Comment: Those flags are meant for your C code, not for Go, `clang -Wl,-Bsymbolic -shared ...` or `g++ -shared -Wl,-Bsymbolic -Wall ...`. The go archives will be the same as before, you're just using symbolic references to the global definitions.

Comment: I've been adding the flags to my CGO_CFLAGS and CGO_LDFLAGS at the client side as well.